# Handle Logout Button Action of JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx, actionlistener

Here is part of my code that shows error. This is done inside `public void start` method. I have already done the Login part, whenever user logs in the id and password remains in the TextField. Which is why I have created a logout button so that when user clicks on it, I want the `useridtextfield` & `passwordtextfield` to be empty.

```
LogoutButton.setOnAction(e-> 
        UserIdTextField==null;    
        PasswordTextField==null;);
```

I have searched over the internet about this problem but got no solution regarding JavaFX Logout handling. I have no idea about FXML so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you want to do `UserIdTextField.setText("");` instead of `UserIdTextField==null`.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: Thanks bro, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for a lambda expression with multiple statements is

```
logoutButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    /* statements */
});
```

(I.e. you need to delimit the statements with `{` ... `}`.)

As pointed out in the comments, comparing the text fields to null is probably not what you want to do here, but it will at least compile.